# Call wPaint extended function

Tags: jquery, extend

I have extended the functions of wPaint in a plugin file like this:

$.fn.wPaint.extend({
    mask: function () {
       ...
      }
  });

I can call it from within the plugin file with this.mask(); without problem.

I need to call it in an initialisation js but I can not find the right syntax. So far, I tried a few ones, including:

```
var ee1 = $('#wPaint').wPaint;
ee1.mask();
```

or

```
$('#wPaint').wPaint.mask();
```

but without success (mask is not a function) !

Expert advice needed, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

$('#wPaint').wPaint('mask');